# Age gate during install when using an NSIS package

Tags: datetime, user-input, nsis, restriction

I have no idea if anyone has attempted this before (and especially considering the standards for this) but has anyone ever programmed an age gate into an NSIS installer for apps that revolve around restricted themes, content or entertainment? I ask this for the most obvious of common reasons by which a reputable marketplace would otherwise reject your submission:

1. The presence of sexual themes (as in "fifty shades" if you want to be extra specific)
2. Apps referencing the use or depiction of regulated products (beer, cannabis, vaping)
3. Games with extreme language or suggestive themes (ESRB Class M or equivalent)

Any ideas?

Comment: This can be easily achieved by adding custom page to installer where user has to enter his age or birth date. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

For actual games, you can register them with [Windows Games Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee415244%28v%3Dvs.85%29). [`IGameExplorer::VerifyAccess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee419032(v%3Dvs.85)) can tell you if the game is blocked by parental controls. While you technically can call this method in the installer, it might give the wrong results if your installer requests UAC elevation because the installer might run under the parents account, not the child's account. The game should call it every time it is started. The Game Explorer API seems to be crippled in newer versions of Windows 10 but should work fine on Vista, 7, 8 and 8.1.

You can create a custom page in NSIS to ask for (and verify) specific information:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
Page Custom MyVerifyPageCreate MyVerifyPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

!define MIN_AGE 21
Var Age

Function MyVerifyPageCreate
!ifmacrodef MUI_HEADER_TEXT
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah" "Blah blah blah"
!endif
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 10u 21u 100% 12u "Blah blah blah age ${MIN_AGE} blah blah"
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateNumber} 10u 35u 30u 12u "$Age"
Pop $1
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd

Function MyVerifyPageLeave
${NSD_GetText} $1 $Age
${If} $Age < ${MIN_AGE}
    MessageBox MB_IconStop "You must be at least ${MIN_AGE} to install $(^Name)!"
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Or if the user needs to enter a date:

```
!include MUI2.nsh
Page Custom MyVerifyPageCreate MyVerifyPageLeave
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!define /IfNDef GDT_VALID 0
!define /IfNDef DTS_LONGDATEFORMAT 4
!define /IfNDef /math DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME 0x1000 + 1

!define MIN_AGE 18

Function MyVerifyPageCreate
!ifmacrodef MUI_HEADER_TEXT
!insertmacro MUI_HEADER_TEXT "Blah" "Blah blah blah"
!endif
System::Call 'COMCTL32::InitCommonControlsEx(*l0x10000000008)'
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0
${NSD_CreateLabel} 10u 21u -20u 25u "Blah blah blah age ${MIN_AGE} blah blah$\r$\n$\r$\nEnter your birthday:"
Pop $0
nsDialogs::CreateControl SysDateTimePick32 ${DEFAULT_STYLES}|${WS_TABSTOP}|${DTS_LONGDATEFORMAT} ${__NSD_Text_EXSTYLE} 10u 50u 200u 12u "" ; Probably only works on Win98 and higher
Pop $1
nsDialogs::Show
FunctionEnd


Function MyVerifyPageLeave
; NOTE: Does not deal with leap years etc!
System::Call 'USER32::SendMessage(p$1, i${DTM_GETSYSTEMTIME}, p0, @r2)i.r0'
${If} $0 = ${GDT_VALID}
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::SystemTimeToFileTime(pr2,*l.r2)'
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetSystemTimeAsFileTime(*l.r3)' ; Current time (UTC)
    System::Call 'KERNEL32::FileTimeToLocalFileTime(*lr3,*l.r3)'
    System::Int64Op ${MIN_AGE} * 315360000000000 ; 1 year (KB 188768)
    System::Int64Op $2 + 
    Pop $2
    ${IfThen} $2 L< $3 ${|} StrCpy $0 "OK" ${|}
${EndIf}
${If} $0 != "OK"
    MessageBox MB_IconStop "You must be at least ${MIN_AGE} to install $(^Name)!"
    Abort
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's no longer possible. The game explorer was removed from Windows because its connected service dependencies were shut down by Microsoft in favor of the current Xbox integration. (That's also why GTA4 recently had to sacrifice its multiplayer to even be allowed to get back on Steam - all of the servers required for these verifications are completely non-existent.)

Comment: I should probably also mention that long-term I would prefer the whole month/day/year method to lessen the chance that someone will... er, "game the system" (for lack of a better term). While the simple number method will do for now, I want something on a long-term basis where customers basically have to concentrate on what they're doing and therefore have a much better chance at taking a second look at what's being asked of their time.

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing up "Games for Windows Live" and "Games Explorer" here? Games Explorer is no longer visible in Explorer but I believe the API is still supported. Games Explorer also never required a internet connection. I know it used to work in early versions of Windows 10 but I have not tested in a while.

Comment: Either way, they're both nonexistent these days.

And one last thing: can you redo the date/time picker for long date format?

Comment: The Games Explorer API is still there in the latest insider build but it looks like it just returns OK without doing anything. Pretty sad Microsoft!

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking would happen. But even before you checked the possibility I was already set on the age gate method so that wasn't even being considered, and the only thing left at this point is to see if you can update your full input version to use a long-form readout (so that it's Wednesday April 8 2020 instead of just 4/8/2020) which would be much easier to read.

Comment: I made it long form now but I'm not sure if it will display the name of the day, depends on your locale settings perhaps.